# Deploy maven tar.gz artifact as build output without assembly plugin

Tags: maven

In my Maven build, I call a script that produce some tar.gz artifact. How to specify to maven groupId, artifactId, version and packaging, so it deployed final tar.gz to artifactory during `mvn deploy`?

My challenge it that this is possible to achieve with assembly plugin, but not when artifact is output if arbitrary script.

For example: let's assume that my shell produce `ABC.tar.gz` with some groupId and artifactId. And my version is `0.0.1`.
I want to deploy `ABC.tar.gz` to artifactory so in pom file of next projects, I was able to reference it like:

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>my_group</groupId>
  <artifactId>ABC</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1</version>
  <type>tar.gz</type>
</dependency>
```

And maven download `ABC.tar.gz` into `.m2`.

For set of reasons, I do not want to use assembly plugin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`build-helper:attach-artifact`](http://www.mojohaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/attach-artifact-mojo.html) goal of the [Build Helper Maven Plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/index.html):

> Attach additional artifacts to be installed and deployed.

```xml
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
  <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.10</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>attach-artifacts</id>
      <phase>package</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>attach-artifact</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <artifacts>
          <artifact>
            <file>${project.build.directory}/path/to/targz</file>
            <type>tar.gz</type>
          </artifact>
        </artifacts>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

This will attach the tar.gz file with the same groupId, artifactId and version as of your current Maven project. This additional artifact will be deployed and installed just like the main artifact of the project.